# c++ program pausing in middle with console in entry mode

Tags: c++11, dictionary

I am writing a program that allows a user to make a tournament of 3 on 3 fantasy creatures. The actual fighting part of the tournament works fine but after my last cout line saying who won the last fight when I try to output the standings a blank space like when there is a cin shows up but if enter anything nothing happens. I am sure there are much more elgant ways to do my maps but I cant understand why even the top line of my cout with no variables would not show up. This is only the portion of the code after the battles are over. points and standing are both int, int maps.

```
for (int i=1; i<7;i++)
{
    for (int j=1; j<7;i++)
    {
        if ((points[i]==points[j])&&(i!=j))
        {
            int tie=rand()%2;
            if (tie==0)
            {
                points[i]=points[i]+1;
            }
            else
            {
                points[j]=points[j]+1;
            }
        }
    }
}
for (int i=1;i<7;i++)
{
    standing[(points[i])]=i;
}
map <int,int>::iterator k;
k=standing.begin();
cout << "These are the final standings. \n";
cout << "Please note fighters 1-3 are player 1 and \n";
cout << "4-6 are from player 2. \n";
cout << "In first place is fighter #" << k->second;
cout << " with " << k->first << "points \n";
k++;
cout << "In second place is fighter #" << k->second;
cout << " with " << k->first << "points \n";
k++;
cout << "In third place is fighter #" << k->second;
cout << " with " << k->first << "points \n";
return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

`for (int j=1; j<7;i++)` is an infinite loop - you probably meant `j++` at the end.  As a result, the `cout` lines are never executed.